# Why is the codimension of $c_0$ inside the space $c$ of convergent sequences is equal to $1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the proof to the following claim:

> **Claim:** The codimension of $c_0$ inside the space $c$ of convergent sequences is equal to $1$.

*Proof:* For every $x=(x_n)_1^{\infty}\in c$, $x+c_0=a(\textbf{1}+c_0)$ where $a=\lim x_n$ and $\textbf{1}$ is the constant sequence with all its terms equal to $1$. So, $[x]=a[\textbf{1}]$.

Then the proof ends. My question is: how does $[x]=a[\textbf{1}]$ imply that $\operatorname{codim}_cc_0=\operatorname{dim}c/c_0=1$?

Comment: That way of doing it is saying "given a convergent sequence $x_n$, you can write $x_n=a \mathbf{1} + b_n$ where $a=\lim x_n$ and $b_n \in c_0$". Since $\{ a \mathbf{1} : a \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is 1D, you get the codimension (i.e. the dimension of the space you need to direct sum with $c_0$ to get all of the convergent sequences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every element of $c/c_0$ is a multiple of a certain element of $c/c_0$, $\dim(c/c_0)=1$.

Comment: So, is $[\textbf{1}]$ the basis for $c/c_0$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $c_0$ is the kernel of a nice linear map $c\to\Bbb R$.